# mapview for bing maps in android

Tags: android, bing-maps

I am using bing maps for showing the distances between specified places in my app. We are using `SOAP` request for getting the image from bing. that image we are showing in `WebView`.

We want the effect same like shown in bing map website like zooming and panning effect. 
But through the SOAP we are unable to do that because, it gives us only one image at a time.

I have tried `ImageView` also for it but, not useful.

I have also tried to used mapview available in android but, it is not useful for these reasons.

1. I am requesting map through the SOAP request.
2. I am not using any API key for getting the map images.
3. It uses "com.google.android.maps" for library.

I would like to know is there any solution for such problem?

Comment: You can add zoom controls to the `WebView`. I don't know if that is enough for you.

Comment: yes we did, but we can not give any effect like zooming in or out and also for panning. We need to send new request again to the server. This makes application slow.

Answer (score 0):

[Bing Maps Android SDK](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/) from InKnowledge might be what you want to use. `BingMapsView` gives you zooming and panning effect without much trouble.